# Synology volume crashed

Tags: backup, redundancy, synology

I have also tried to contact Synology first, but haven't gotten a reply yet. So I was hoping some linux gurus might be able to help out here.

I was upgrading some packages on my DS211J Synology drive. During that process the unit became unresponsive. I could not SSH into the drive, access the web interface or access the shared drives. I left it for some hours to finish working in case it was just using all its resources to do the upgrades.

It did not return, so I tried rebooting by long pressing the power button. This did not help. So eventually I turned off the power and rebooted it that way.

When it came back up it informed me that the volume had crashed. The disks are healthy. I did not see any option to repair the volume. When I SSH'ed into the unit the /volume1 folder was empty, except for an @eadir and @tmp folder. All my files gone.

The two drives were configured in a mirror.

I have turned off the unit now. But is there any way I can recover the files that were on /volume1? Why have they been deleted?

I have not tried to recreate the volume. I have only tried to find the files that were missing.

Ironically I was upgrading the packages so I could set up an off-site backup plan.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing is happening  to me except idont think I've lost any data yet 
Unresponsive web SSH slow 
I pulled out three  two drives after shutting down and it came back up more responsive I then updated DSM and did smart test all OK 
Restarted with sll drives back in and last two took ages to come back but second drive was degraded and remains so

Comment: Thanks... I'll try that.

Comment: Didn't work, but Synology support were ale to recreate the volume.